Solving equation with complex exponents
I have been looking for a way to solve the following equation:
$a=1-|r|^{2}=1-r_r^2-r_i^2$ with $r=\frac{H_{12}-H_{I}}{H_{R}-H_{12}}e^{2ik_{0}x_{1}}$ and $r_r$ and $r_i$ denoting the real and imaginary components of $r$.
$H_{12}$ denotes a complex transfer function of the form $H_{12}=H_x+H_yi$, where $H_x$ and $H_y$ are known real quantities. $H_I$ and $H_R$ are given by the following: $H_I=e^{-ik_0s}, H_R=e^{ik_0s}$
Further, $k_0$ is a complex number of the form $k_0=k_R+k_Ii$ where $k_R$ and $k_I$ are known real quantities. $x_1$ and $s$ are also known real quantities.
What would be the best way to approach solving for $a$? Is there a key simplification that can be made?

I understand you need the value of $a$ so you need $r_r$ and $r_i$ so:
$$a=1-|r|^2$$
$$|r|^2=r_r^2+r_i^2$$
$$\omega =e^{2 k_o i}$$
$$k_o=k_R+ik_I$$
$$\omega =e^{2i(k_R+ik_I) }=e^{2 ik_R }e^{- 2 k_I }$$
$$r=T_f\omega^{x_1}=T_fe^{- 2 k_I x_1 }e^{2 k_R x_1 i }$$
You have all the values $k_o$,$s$ , etc to calculate and separate real from imaginary part of the $T_f$
$$T_f=\frac{H_{12}-H_{I}}{H_{R}-H_{12}}=T_R+iT_I$$
$$r=(T_R+iT_I)e^{- 2 k_I x_1 }(cos(2 k_R x_1)+isin(2 k_R x_1))$$
$$r_r =T_R e^{- 2 k_I x_1 }cos(2 k_R x_1)-T_Ie^{- 2 k_I x_1 }sin(2 k_R x_1)$$
$$r_i =T_R e^{- 2 k_I x_1 }sin(2 k_R x_1)+T_Ie^{- 2 k_I x_1 }cos(2 k_R x_1)$$

Thank you for this insight @phionez , it has been very helpful for my understanding. I have worked through the derivation for $T_R$ and $T_I$ and have come up with the following:
$T_R=\frac{MK+LN}{M^2+N^2}$ and $T_I=\frac{-NK+LM}{M^2+N^2}$
where $K=H_x-e^{sk_I}cos(-sk_R)$, $L=H_y-e^{sk_I}sin(-sk_R)$, $M=e^{-sk_I}cos(sk_R)-H_x$ and $N=e^{-sk_I}sin(sk_R)-H_y$

Remember cos(-x)=cos(x) and sin(-x)=-sin(x) for your expressions.
